# Indy10 HTTPS - socket error 10060 - connection timeout

Tags: sockets, delphi, ssl, https, indy10

I'm getting "Socket Error #10060, Connection timed out" when trying to access a https link.

Here is how you can reproduce it with **INDY 10.6.2.0** and OpenSSL 1.0.2d DLLs (also happens with older Indy 10 version and dlls):

- create a project and add a TButton, TIdHTTP and TMemo objects to the form
- add to button onclick this code:

  ```
  IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent:='Indy';
  IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects:=true;
  Memo1.text:=IdHTTP1.Get('https://www.itv.com');`
  ```
- now compile and run it, it will download correctly the file.
- BUT if you are using a service like **www.smartydns.com** which redirects DNS request to their server, INDY sample above will not work and fail with **"Socket Error #10060, Connection timed out"** message.

Have tried it with WGET too (https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/) and in version 1.13 its initializing the SSL handshake and freezes, but works without problems with version 1.15.

**So the question is, what IdHTTP settings do I have to use to make it work, or is it a bug in Indy10 ?**

Comment: Use a packet sniffer to analyze the differences in DNS requests and SSL handshaking between WGET 1.13 and WGET 1.15. That should get you a better clue as to what you may need to apply to `TIdHTTP` to make it work. FYI, you are using `TIdHTTP`'s *default* TLS setup. Per Indy's [Changelog blog article](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/blogs/ChangeLog/20141222.aspx) on that feature: "*If you need to customize [SSL/TLS settings], then you will still have to explicitly assign an SSLIOHandler component to the TIdHTTP.IOHandler property [and configure it as needed] before sending an HTTPS request*"

Comment: Thanks for your reply @RemyLebeau, I've tried with different configurations of SSLIOHandler too, still no joy :( Could it be an issue only under  Delphi7?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I've made more tests with Wireshark, with wget 1.3 it says "Header checksum: 0x0000 [incorrect, should be 0xa9fc (may be caused by "IP checksum offload"?)] ". Also on WGET 1.15 changelog it says "Do not fail on non fatal GNU TLS alerts during handshake." [link](http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=7863). Note that you can trial for free www.smartydns.com.

Comment: Here is the original bug report for wget: [Improve handling of SSL/TLS alerts with GnuTLS](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-wget/2013-05/msg00033.html). I don't think OpenSSL has an option to ignore non-fatal alerts.

Comment: I found this in the [OpenSSL documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_options.html): "a bug in OpenSSL clients earlier than 0.9.8m (all of which are unpatched) will result in the connection hanging if it receives a no_renegotiation alert. OpenSSL versions 0.9.8m and later will regard a no_renegotiation alert as fatal and respond with a fatal handshake_failure alert. This is because the OpenSSL API currently has no provision to indicate to an application that a renegotiation attempt was refused".  Maybe it also plays into other alerts.

Comment: It looks like other SSL implementations are also affected by mishandling of warning alerts during handshaking, such as PolarSSL: [Mishandling of non-fatal alerts (client-side)](https://tls.mbed.org/discussions/bug-report-issues/mishandling-of-non-fatal-alerts-client-side)

Comment: I see, so there is no chance to make IdHTTP work in this situation?

Comment: If the problem really is caused by OpenSSL failing on a warning alert, then it is an OpenSSL issue, not an Indy issue. On the other hand, I just found that if you assign an `OnStatusInfo` or `OnStatusInfoEx` event handler to the SSLIOHandler, then Indy registers a callback that is called on status events, which should include alerts, where the `where` parameter includes the `SSL_CB_ALERT` flag, and the `ret` parameter indicates the type of alert. But the callback can't tell OpenSSL whether to ignore the alert or not.

Comment: I get the following from OnStatusInfo:  
"before/connect initialization"  
"SSLv3 write client hello A"  -- here the timeout message is shown  
"SSLv3 read server hello A"  

On normal connection or using other DNS service I get:
SSL status: "before/connect initialization"
"SSLv3 write client hello A"
"SSLv3 read server hello A"
"SSLv3 read server certificate A"
"SSLv3 read server key exchange A"
"SSLv3 read server done A"
"SSLv3 write client key exchange A"
"SSLv3 write change cipher spec A"
SSLv3 write finished A
SSLv3 flush data
SSLv3 read finished A  
SSL negotiation finished successfully

Comment: `OnStatusInfo` only gives you text messages. `OnStatusInfoEx` gives you more details.

Comment: Does the server require a certificate ?
Just a clue